# why 'database not selected' error is popping up?

Tags: php, mysql

have a look at this code

```
include_once("includes/config.php");
include_once("includes/classes.php");
include_once("includes/functions.php");
$db = new MySQLDatabase();
function do_something(){
    $db = new MySQLDatabase();
    unset($db);
}
do_something();
$db->query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$db->query();
$result = $db->fetch_array();
var_dump($result);
echo"</pre>";
unset($db);
```

you only need to see MySQLDatabase class from classes.php among all the includes and here is it

```
class MySQLDatabase{
        public $query = "";
        private $last_query = "";
        private $query_result;
        private $connection;
        function __construct(){
            $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER_NAME,DB_PASSWORD);
            $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$this->connection);
            if((!$this->connection) || (!$db_select)){
                die("can't connect to database<br/> ERROR : ".mysql_error());
            }
        }
        public function get_last_query(){
            return $this->last_query;
        }
        private function escape_query(){
            mysql_real_escape_string($this->query);
        }
        public function query(){
            $this->escape_query();
            $this->query_result = mysql_query($this->query);
            $this->check_result();
            $this->last_query = $this->query;
            return $this->query_result;
        }
        private function check_result(){
            if(!$this->query_result){
                die("mysql query failed<br/>query :".$this->query."<br/> Eror :".mysql_error()."<br>".$this->last_query."<br>");
            } else{
                return 1;
            }
        }
        public function fetch_array(){
            $ass_array = array();
            while($temp = mysql_fetch_array($this->query_result)){
                array_push($ass_array,$temp);
            }
            return $ass_array;
        }

        public function num_rows(){
            if(is_bool($this->query_result)){
                return $this->query_result;
            } else{
            return mysql_num_rows($this->query_result);
            }
        }

        public function affected_rows(){
            //return mysql_affected_rows($this->query_result);
            if(is_bool($this->query_result)){
                return $this->query_result;
            } else{
            return mysql_affected_rows($this->query_result);
            }
        }

        public function close_connection(){
            mysql_close($this->connection);
        }
        function __destruct(){
            $this->close_connection();
        }
    }
```

My question is
**When i try to create a new object of MySQLDatabase($db) class why it mess up with global $db, I mean at the time of unset($db) in function it is unsetting global $db and i am getting error as shown here**
[image: error]

**and this error still appears even if i change variable name in function?**

```
include_once("includes/config.php");
include_once("includes/classes.php");
include_once("includes/functions.php");
$db = new MySQLDatabase();
function do_something(){
    $dbl = new MySQLDatabase();
    unset($dbl);
}
do_something();
$db->query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$db->query();
$result = $db->fetch_array();
var_dump($result);
echo"</pre>";
unset($db);
```

possible solution that i think of:

In this code i am trying to make two parllel connection to database one using $db object and another using $dbl object, may it is not possible with MySQL to make two parllel connection!!

Comment: Check your DB_NAME in your class by var_dump.

Comment: Why use a `mysql_*` wrapper instead of using `mysqli`? You seem to be mimicking the behaviour of `mysqli` anyway.

Comment: @Aslad Liton
file containg MySQLDatabase also include config.php and config.php file defines all these constants, I have tried to echo DB_NAME from file containing MySQLDatabase class it works fine and show me the value of database i want to select.

Comment: @kba I have learned php mysql from a book which teaches it in mysql_*() way, since it these functions will not be supported in future versions of php i will learn these mysqli_* objects,function very soon, but right i only know these old function approach to access mysql..
I will be very thankful if you can tell me a good resource to learn this mysqli_* stuff..

Comment: If you are already familiar with `mysql_*`, I believe the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/mysqli) is sufficient. At least that's the resource I used to make my transition. It holds [many examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php).

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is not related to variable scope at-large. PHP's variable scope is [very well-defined](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Your problem stems from the you calling [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/mysql_query) in `MySQLDatabase::query` without the second parameter of the function (the "link indentifer"). While the parameter *is* optional, [according to the documentation](http://www.php.net/mysql_query):

> If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` is assumed.

Since the database link you last opened, the one inside `do_something`, was closed, PHP no longer has a database link to refer to on subsequent calls to `mysql_query`.

Try updating updating this line:

```
$this->query_result = mysql_query($this->query);
```

To explicity refer to the database link property inside your class:

```
$this->query_result = mysql_query($this->query, $this->connection);
```